# first value onchange not working for dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, triggers

i have a dropdown,on change of that next dropdown is populated
onchange of that dropdown another list will show,but onchange is not working for first value ,i tried trigger too,its not working

```
 $('#job_type').on('change', function(evt) {
      var tt =$("#job option:first").val();
          $('#job')
   .val(tt)
   .trigger('change');
       loadJob();

    });
    $('#job').on('change', function() {


$(".job_error").html("");
        $('#sort_list_assigned').html('');

        var parent = $('#job').find(":selected").text();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/ajax/Hierarchymaping/getJobUpdatedList',
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            data: {
                parent: parent
            },
            success: function(response) {
                if ($.trim(response)) {
                    $('#reset_all_jobs').show();
                    response.forEach(function(item) {
                        $('#sort_list_assigned').append("<input  class='ind_job'   onclick='selectUnselect(this);'    style='float:left;' type='checkbox' checked='checked'   data-job= " + item + " value=" + item + "><li class='sortable-item selected' data-activity=" + item + " data-id=" + item + " style='margin-left:20px;' id=" + item + ">" + item + "</li>");
                    });


                }
            }
        });

    });
```

my HTML is also attaching here,i dont know why trigger is not working here

```
<select id="job_type" class="dd_config" style="width: 265px">
                                    <option value=0>--Select--</option>
                                    <?php
                                    //Initial load of activities 
                                    foreach ($all_jobstype_object as $type_index => $type) {
                                        echo '<option value="' . $type_index . '">' . $type . '</option>';
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <label class="lbc">Choose Job </label>  
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <select id="job" class="dd_config" style="width: 265px">
                                    <option value=0>--Select--</option>
                                </select>
                                 <span class="message job_error"></span>
                        </tr>
```

Comment: Please be so kind and show us your html

Comment: tried this too,nothing coming

Comment: I've tried your code in a fiddle and it works fine. Are you sure there are no error in the console?

Comment: @singo,i didnt see error in console

Comment: Can you check `<option value=0>--Select--</option>` there `"` for `value` is missing

Comment: i removed that and also checked sinto,kittunilla :(

Comment: check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bsg30m1w/1/), as you can see both the console log works as soon as you change the dropdown

Comment: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at RegExp.exec (<anonymous>)

Comment: Sorry that was my mistake

Comment: mistake? what happend

Comment: Can you check this code, I do not have your ajax funuction but I think what you need will be here. https://jsfiddle.net/ywhadxeb/1/

Comment: here only one onchange happening,my issue is with second onchange first value

Comment: second onchange? of `#job`. do you check by console on success?